# Unexpected blank appears in the middle of my environment after I give an optional parameter to it

Tags: environments

I tried to make an environment like **theorem**. Below is what I have tried so far:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{numdef}[subsection]
\setcounter{numdef}{0}
\renewcommand\thenumdef{\arabic{numdef}}

\newenvironment{ntdef}[1][]{
    \vspace*{.2em}
    \newcommand\makedef{\stepcounter{numdef}
        \textit{Definition}\ \thesubsection.\thenumdef: 
    }
    \noindent\makedef
}{\par\vspace{.2em}}

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \subsection{B}
    \noindent\textit{Definition}\ 1.1.0\ \textit{(Definition 1)}: This is a template\par
    \begin{ntdef}[Definition 1]
        This is the first difinition
    \end{ntdef}

    \begin{ntdef}
        This is the second difinition
    \end{ntdef}
\end{document}
```

I used the plain text to show the template what I except as the first tow lines show.

In my project, the environment should have an optional parameters(to display more distinct, **I have moved the funtion that is displaying the given parameter in this test project**). The environment worked well when no option is given. But once I gived the name in option, an unexpected blank appears in horizontal as the second line shows.

[image]

What causes this strange problem?

Comment: well you have various spaces in your definition. End of lines can create a space, as they do it you type normal text. So hide them with e.g. `{%`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tried to add `%` to every line of my environment defining, but it seems not help. Could you give me a specific example?

Comment: You've not given us the code you're using, nor the output of the code you've given us.  So it's hard to say what's wrong.  What's `\makedef`?  And is there a reason you don't want to use the amsthm package, which already does this?

Comment: @campa The second "This is a template" is not present.  But OP is also not showing us their attempt at adding `%` to every line that seems not to help.

Comment: @Teepeemm Upps, sorry. I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why not using `\newtheorem`. Anyway, you need to remove spaces and you want `\addvspace` rather than `\vspace`, so as not to accumulate vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcounter{numdef}[subsection]
\setcounter{numdef}{0}
\renewcommand\thenumdef{\arabic{numdef}}

\newenvironment{ntdef}[1][]{%
  \par\addvspace{.2em}
  \newcommand\makedef{%
    \stepcounter{numdef}%
    \textit{Definition}\ \thesubsection.\thenumdef: \ignorespaces
  }%
  \noindent\makedef
}{\par\addvspace{.2em}}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\subsection{B}

\noindent\textit{Definition}\ 1.1.0\ \textit{(Definition 1)}: This is a template

\begin{ntdef}[Definition 1]
  This is the first definition
\end{ntdef}

\begin{ntdef}
  This is the second definition
\end{ntdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\newtheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{enkidudefinition}
  {0.2em}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0.2em}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape}    % HEADFONT
  {\normalfont:}% HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}            % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{enkidudefinition}
\newtheorem{ntdef}{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\subsection{B}

\noindent\textit{Definition}\ 1.1.0\ \textit{(Definition 1)}: This is a template

\begin{ntdef}[Definition 1]
  This is the first definition
\end{ntdef}

\begin{ntdef}
  This is the second definition
\end{ntdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the note in italics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{enkidudefinition}
  {0.2em}       % ABOVESPACE
  {0.2em}       % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape}    % HEADFONT
  {\normalfont:}% HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{\textup{#2}}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{enkidudefinition}
\newtheorem{ntdef}{Definition}[subsection]

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\subsection{B}

\noindent\textit{Definition}\ 1.1.0\ \textit{(Definition 1)}: This is a template

\begin{ntdef}[Definition 1]
  This is the first definition
\end{ntdef}

\begin{ntdef}
  This is the second definition
\end{ntdef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\ignorespaces` works, so adding a `%` after the `[]` if there is a parameter and a following wrapping around does. Thanks. Also, your exposition of theorem is very helpful for me.